# Swiper пагинация is not a function

Tags: javascript, swiper

У меня есть несколько слайдеров с пагинацией на странице и они работают как и задумывалось, но если перейти на любую другую страницу, то я получаю ошибку slider.el.querySelector is not a function
Проблема именно в коде пагинации.

```
//Сами слайдеры
let slideArr = [];

const slider1 = new Swiper('#intro-slider', {
    effect:'fade',
    slidesPerView: 'auto',

    fadeEffect: {
        crossFade: true
    },

    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.intro__arrows-next',
        prevEl: '.intro__arrows-prev'
    },

    pagination: {
        el: '.intro__swiper-pagination',
        type: 'progressbar'
    }
});

const slider2 = new Swiper('#reviews-slider', {

    slidesPerView: 1.2,
    spaceBetween: 30,

    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.reviews__arrows-next',
        prevEl: '.reviews__arrows-prev'
    },

    pagination: {
        el: '.reviews__swiper-pagination',
        type: 'progressbar'
    },

    breakpoints: {
        575: {
            slidesPerView: 1
        }
    }
});

slideArr.push(slider1);
slideArr.push(slider2);
```

```
// Панинация, которая на других страницах выдает ошибку 'slider.el.querySelector is not a function'

function formatFraction (number) {
    if (number < 10) {
        number = '0' + number;
    }
    return number;
};


slideArr.forEach(slider => {
    const total = slider.el.querySelector('.pagination-slider-total');
    if(total) {
        const curr = slider.el.querySelector('.pagination-slider-current');

        total.innerHTML = formatFraction(slider.slides.length);

        slider.on('slideChange', function() {
            let currSlideNum = slider.realIndex + 1;
            currSlideNum = formatFraction(currSlideNum);
            curr.innerHTML = currSlideNum;
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто проверяйте наличие слайдера на странице перед тем как его инициализировать.

На jq:

```
if($('#test').length > 0){
    инициализация
}
```

На js:

```
let element = document.getElementById("test");

if(typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null){ 
    инициализация
}
```

Comment: извиняюсь, я не сразу понял, что решение мне не помогло. Я по прежнему получаю ошибку, когда нахожусь на любой другой странице.
У меня же в коде есть подобная проверка  if(total) {}